# Blocking connections to a specific IP address by mac address in iptables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, ubuntu, iptables

I'm trying to set a rule so that computers that connect to my network need to be added to an iptables rule list before they are granted access to the modem (internet).

My network is currently:

MODEM----->Server----->Switch------>PCS

I'm currently trying to use the rule:

`iptables --policy FORWARD DROP`

`iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.1 -m mac --mac-source 78:e4:00:8e:fe:63 -j ACCEPT`

Connections to 192.168.1.1 (modem) are blocked, but the accept rule doesn't allow connections from that mac address to reach 192.168.1.1. The server has two network interfaces that are bridged (eth0 and eth1).

Comment: Please accept your other questions' answers. There's a checkbox outline under the answer's vote count. Clicking the arrow will accept the question.

Comment: Rob Olmos: Done, didn't even know that was there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to be using [ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/) when working with a bridge interface like that. Take a peek into that, but that's probably where you want to go.